# I am trying to generate random color codes using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, colors, color-codes

I am trying to generate random color codes or one base colour-based codes. I am not much familiar with JavaScript & coloring

What I have gathered so far:

```
function getColors(len) {
  var colors = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    colors.push(color);
  }

  return colors;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your inner loop should use something other than `i`, consider using `j`, or using `let` instead of `var`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood  you correctly. Try below function. It returns you the collection of colors if you pass anything and random. But if you pass `baseColor` it will generate `hue` set of colors based on `basedColor`. `hue` defined base colors are : `red`,`yellow`,`green`,`cyan`,`blue` & `magenta`.

**Usage**

example: 1 - `getRandomColors(10)` or `getRandomColors(10,'random')` or `getRandomColors(10,'anything besides Hue')`

result : `//(10) ["#C4AD05", "#B63DCB", "#22A9FE", "#59DCAC", "#986FFD", "#493E56", "#49693D", "#83029A", "#59E3C0", "#C6FB84"]`

example: 2 - `getRandomColors(10,'blue') //baseColor`

result: `//(10) ["hsl(240, 79%, 19%)", "hsl(240, 44%, 45%)", "hsl(240, 13%, 64%)", "hsl(240, 63%, 73%)", "hsl(240, 52%, 45%)", "hsl(240, 61%, 83%)", "hsl(240, 46%, 58%)", "hsl(240, 35%, 6%)", "hsl(240, 89%, 89%)", "hsl(240, 76%, 97%)"]`

**Code**

```
function getRandomColors(len, baseColor = 'random') {
        var colors = [];
        var baseValue = getColorValue(baseColor);
        var execFn = getExecFn(baseValue);

        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            colors.push(execFn());
        }

        return colors;

        function getExecFn(baseColorValue) {
            if (baseColorValue == -1) {
                return getRandomColor;
            }
            else {
                return hueSet;
            }
        }

        function hueSet() {
            h = baseValue;
            s = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
            l = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
            return 'hsl(' + h + ', ' + s + '%, ' + l + '%)';
        }

        function getRandomColor() {
            var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
            var color = '#';
            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
            }
            return color;
        }

        function getColorValue(baseColor) {
            switch (baseColor.toLowerCase()) {
                case 'red':
                    return 0;
                case 'yellow':
                    return 60;
                case 'green':
                    return 120;
                case 'cyan':
                    return 180;
                case 'blue':
                    return 240;
                case 'magenta':
                    return 300;
                default:
                    return -1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted and what I had in mind when I posted my question but due to my lack in the technology couldn't much ponder on it...

Thanks mate... :)

Answer (score 1):

For my part, I prossessed as follows:

```
var RGBColor1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(255));
var RGBColor2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(255));
var RGBColor3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(255));
colors.push(RGBColor1);
colors.push(RGBColor2)
colors.push(RGBColor3)
```

You can do a loop to go faster

Comment: `Math.floor(255)`? :)

Comment: It's exemple to MDN : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Math/random

Comment: @MaximeROGOGINE that's to handle floats etc as input. Since you know `255` you don't need to floor it

Comment: It's not false ! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't break anything but is seems pointless. Its like doing `255 * 1`, there is no point to doing it

Comment: Thanks for your kind effort mates...
This  helps a bit but doesn't really fulfilled what I wanted...

But anywways thanks :)